# Add Class To Body Using ERB In A View - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I've watched [this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/30-pretty-page-title) to add a page title when in a view, is there a way I can do the same but add a class the body tag?

Comment: jQuery? `$('body').addClass('mysexyclass');`

Comment: I didn't really want to have scripts inside the views

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Not sure what you mean, you can do it the same way:

In a view:

```
<% content_for :body_class, "my_class" %>
```

In a layout file:

```
<body class="<%= yield (:body_class) %>">
```

Comment: Is there a way to stop `<body class>` on other pages?

Comment: Not sure if there's actually an elegant way to this in ERB. The not so elegant way is to just do a helper call inside the body tag and return the whole body class ("my_class") together with the "class" attribute. Note that the yield(:body_class) call will return an empty string when no value is set so you can just check for that.

Comment: @user1919937 I've never been satisfied with this approach because of the <body class> on other pages. See my approach below.

Answer (score 5):

I usually make a helper method for stuff like this so you can have defaults set up cleanly

```
application_helper.rb
  def body_class(class_name="default_class")
    content_for :body_class, class_name
  end


view:
  <% body_class "foo" %>

application.html.erb
  <body class="<%= yield (:body_class) %>">
```

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes using the current controller name as a class name we'll do:

```
<body class="<%= controller.controller_name %>">
```

I find this simpler and a bit more elegant, but of course thus you won't be able to assign individual class names.

s. [Add Class To Body Using ERB In A View - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995927/add-class-to-body-using-erb-in-a-view-rails)

Answer (score 1):

In the layout page:

```
<% if content_for?(:body_class) %>
  <body class="<%= content_for(:body_class) %>" >
<% else %>
 <body>
<% end %>
```

In the content page:

```
<% content_for :body_class do  'my-body-class' end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use the following method:

`<body class="<%= content_for?(:body_class) ? yield(:body_class) : controller_name %>">`

That method avoids the dreaded `<body class>`.

I frequently use the controller name to scope a number of styles so it's nice to not need to supply a content_for on every view if I only needed that one class.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the accepted method in my app for a while, but never really loved how it worked, because if there is no class, you're gonna have that class=' ' on your body tag, littering your code. For my current use case, I just wanted a widescreen class (but you could easily get more advanced with different classes per your use case). I'm happy with this approach:

In your application helper:

```
def body_tag(&block)
  content = capture(&block)
  content_tag(:body, content, class: @widescreen ? "widescreen" : nil)
end
```

In application.html.erb

```
<%= body_tag do %>
  <%# the rest of your content here %>
<% end %>
```

Then in your application controller:

```
private
  def enable_widescreen
    @widescreen = true
  end
```

Then in any controller that you want it, just do:

```
before_action :enable_widescreen
```

Then feel free to make the class logic more advanced if you want to use it for different classes besides 'widescreen' - but the point is that this is an elegant way to allow for there NOT to be a class if you don't specify one, without

```
<body class>
```

showing up in your html.